# Pure managed SQLite NET wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, sqlite-net

I am looking for a pure-manage SQLite wrapper. I believe there used to be one several years back but whatever I try off NuGet seems to depend on `SQLite.Interop.dll` - which is what I want to get rid of.

I have tried: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.MSIL/ but it also depends on `SQLite.Interop.dll`, which was surprising considering no `SQLite.Interop.dll` was added to the project by NuGet.

Furthermore, I tried https://www.nuget.org/packages/Csharp-Sqlite/ but this one failed to open my databases ('unsupported format').

Last but not least, https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net/ depends on `sqlite3.dll`.

Comment: What would this pure-managed wrapper wrap?

Comment: There isn't any that I'm aware of. (At least none that are complete and actively maintained.) Might be helpful if you explain why you need such a library, or what problem you're trying to solve. There might be a different way to get there.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is a library written in C.

To get a pure-managed SQLite, you would have to completely reimplement all of SQLite.
(Csharp-Sqlite tried to do this, but is incomplete and outdated.)

Comment: AFAIK, old System.Data.Sqlite v1.0.66 did this too but it's too old now. Can't read my db files. It used to be possible to have a pure managed library but apparently there is no project that currently maintains this.

Comment: @wpfwannabe I know they used to release "mixed-mode" assemblies, a single dll with both managed and unmanaged code in it. I don't think they ever translated the whole library into .NET.

Comment: The reason is that I want to distribute the app as a monolithic EXE. All referenced assemblies would be embedded as resources and resolved at runtime. Unfortunately, this approach works for pure managed assemblies. Mixed-mode assemblies or native DLLs can't loaded this way. I solved the problem and will post a solution separately.